# Iterate over rows, and perform addition

Tags: python, numpy

So, here I have a numpy array, array([[-1.228,  0.709,  0.   ], [ 0.   ,  2.836,  0.   ], [ 1.228,  0.709,  0.   ]]). What my plan is to perform addition to all the rows of this array with a vector (say [1,2,3]), and then append the result onto the end of it i.e the addition of another three rows? I want to perform the same process, like 5 times, so that the vector is added only to the last three rows, which were the result of the previous calculation(addition). Any suggestions?

Comment: Store each operation in a new array, and at the end of the operation, concatenate the arrays.

Comment: This is a bad idea. You need to keep size of arrays immutable otherwise you waste your time on allocation of memory place for new arrays and creating duplicated copies of arrays inside it. That's not what `numpy` is designed for. `np.append` and `np.concatenate` does these things therefore they are inefficient.

Comment: You might like, however, to keep results of addition in separate arrays. That makes more sense.

Comment: @mathfux Any examples on how can we do that? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `np.append` along the first axis:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[-1.228, 0.709, 0. ], [ 0. , 2.836, 0. ], [ 1.228, 0.709, 0. ]])
v = np.array([1, 2, 3])

new_a = np.append(a, a+v, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the addition part, just write something like `a[0]+[1,2,3]` (where a is your array), numpy will perform addition element-wise as expected.

For appending `a=np.append(a, [line], axis=1)` is what you're looking for, where line is the new line you want to add, for example the result of the previous sum.

The iteration can be easily repeated selecting the last three rows thanks to negative indexing: if you use `a[-1]`, `a[-2]` and `a[-3]` you'll be sure to pick the last three lines

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to keep results within a single array, a better option is to create it at the beginning and perform operations you need on it.

```
arr = np.array([[-1.228, 0.709, 0. ], [ 0. , 2.836, 0. ], [ 1.228, 0.709, 0. ]])
vector = np.array([1,2,3])
N = 5    
multiarr = np.tile(arr, (1,N))
>>> multiarr
array([[-1.228,  0.709,  0.   , -1.228,  0.709,  0.   , -1.228,  0.709, 0.   , -1.228,  0.709,  0.   , -1.228,  0.709,  0.   ], 
       [ 0.   ,  2.836,  0.   ,  0.   ,  2.836,  0.   ,  0.   ,  2.836, 0.   ,  0.   ,  2.836,  0.   ,  0.   ,  2.836,  0.   ], 
       [ 1.228,  0.709,  0.   ,  1.228,  0.709,  0.   ,  1.228,  0.709, 0.   ,  1.228,  0.709,  0.   ,  1.228,  0.709,  0.   ]])
multivector = (vector * np.arange(N)[:, None]).ravel()
>>> multivector
array([ 0,  0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  2,  4,  6,  3,  6,  9,  4,  8, 12])
>>> multiarr + multivector
array([[-1.228,  0.709,  0.   , -0.228,  2.709,  3.   ,  0.772,  4.709,  6.   ,  1.772,  6.709,  9.   ,  2.772,  8.709, 12.   ],
       [ 0.   ,  2.836,  0.   ,  1.   ,  4.836,  3.   ,  2.   ,  6.836,  6.   ,  3.   ,  8.836,  9.   ,  4.   , 10.836, 12.   ],
       [ 1.228,  0.709,  0.   ,  2.228,  2.709,  3.   ,  3.228,  4.709,  6.   ,  4.228,  6.709,  9.   ,  5.228,  8.709, 12.   ]])
```